# jQuery $(document).ready() not firing

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Using jQuery 1.4.2 from Google hosted Code.

Is there a reason why the following javascript does not fire all 3 document.ready functions when the document is ready?

The first `$(document).ready()` function, which renders headers, and the second, which gives a 'Foo' alert box triggered, but subsequent ones in new `<script>` blocks  aren't triggered,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Cufon.replace('h1'); // Works without a selector engine
        Cufon.replace('h2'); // Works without a selector engine
        Cufon.replace('h3'); // Works without a selector engine
        Cufon.now();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () { alert("Number Foo"); });
</script>

// html tags

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { alert("Number One"); });
    $(document).ready(function () { alert("Number Two"); });
</script>
```

These are in seperate web parts, hosted on the same page in Sharepoint2010

Comment: I'd be a bit wary of defining a document ready function inside another document ready function.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Post updated.

Comment: The last $(document).ready function is not well terminated. `});` missing

Comment: Good spot, but that's not the problem...

Comment: Host jquery full locally then put a debugger statement inside the ready iterator and see for yourself. I suspect you must have an error but without more source it is impossible to see

Comment: Each script tag is in a separate web part? We didn't know this before. The problem itself is not in the scripts. Something else in your page is messing up your code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can think of three forensic things to try, right off:

1. try it with non-google-hosted
   libraries.
2. comment out the Cufon
   calls -- I believe Cufon does some
   crazy stuff to download additional
   resources, yes? That may be
   interfering.
3. sub in
   `$(window).load()` for one or more
   of your `$(document).ready()`
   callback defs. They have different
   firing criteria --
   `$(window).load()` waits for
   everything to load up, allegedly --
   but the substitution may be
   revealing.

Of course, `console.log()` and `alert()` will be your in-leu-of-debugger-breakpoint best friends in this case.

Comment: Cufon was the culprit... Removed!

Comment: The $(window).load() tip helped me!

Comment: If $(window).load() works but $(document).ready() doesn't, what does that mean?

Comment: @CharlieMezak: does your script depend on an asset that it assumes is loaded (like an image)? I believe $(document).ready() callbacks fire once all of the documents' scripts, CSS, and HTML are loaded, without waiting for images and other referents.

Comment: Switching to $(window).load() fixed the problem for me but I have no idea why. If anyone could shed any light that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a closing curly bracket and parenthesis in the second script tag

Comment: Nope, this isn't the problem.

Comment: Did you typed your code incorrectly from the beggining or corrected it after the answers?

Comment: I changed it just before your first answer in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `});` in the end of the last $(document).ready

Once you correct this it should work

**EDIT:**
Since you say now that each script tag is in a separate web part I believe the problem itself is not in the scripts. Something else in your page is messing up your code.

Comment: This isn't the problem, as I have fixed the source and it is still not working.