# $(document).ready() not firing after redirect with window.location

Tags: jquery, redirect, document-ready

I have read the other questions

[jQuery $(document).ready() not firing after window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365220/jquery-document-ready-not-firing-after-window-location-href)

[jQuery $(document).ready() not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974675/jquery-document-ready-not-firing)

[Why is $(document).ready not firing for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857072/jquery-why-is-document-ready-not-firing-for-me)

yet none of the solutions seem to work...

My issue is that the jQuery $(document).ready() is not firing in Firefox yet fires in other browsers after the redirect. I know the js gets loaded since it has a time variable appended to the end to keep it from caching.

I have tried using $(window).load() to the same result. Firebug is not showing errors and is showing the script being loaded, however a breakpoint placed on the ready() function never triggers.

Are there some sort of security restrictions in Firefox that could be causing the issue and if so how would I get around them?

Comment: You may want to post sample code to assist others in tracing your issue.  As it is, it could be numerous things.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem when using back/forward. If you're not having this problem with back/forward it's probably a typo. But it could be weird behavior from Firefox.

Here's a simple example that doesn't work for me with the back button (i.e. no event fires, redirects are not involved):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simplest JQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("document.ready");
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    Firefox will not fire document ready on back/forward navigation. Except when it 
    does.<br />
    <a href="navigate-nowhere.html">Go!</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Firefox is definitely showing some bugs as I'm getting different behavior from the same code on different machines. With an up-to-date FF5 it doesn't work on Windows 7 or Leopard. I have another machine on Snow Leopard where it works like it says on the tin.

The problem isn't JQuery either - even dropping it and using addEventListener has no effect. Using the inline event (i.e. via onload in the body tag) has no effect. The "empty unload" trick documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button/2218733#2218733) isn't working either.

Nor is it a problem with extensions - I've tried turning them all off. I tried a clean installation on the Leopard machine without any change.

Interestingly, the focus/onfocus event does work - unless the link is still highlighted in the page. In which case, the window.onblur event does fire afterwards, but only when using tab to change the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Until I can find a better alternative, `<body onUnload="">` works for me in FF5. I think your problem might go a little beyond this fix?